# Angular 5 - Fetching data from the JSON file under the asset folder

Tags: angular

Our application is dynamically generating the Form from a .json file which is placed under the assets folder. The problem we are facing is before the .json file is loaded, our component is rendered and as a result we are seeing null values in the form.

We tried to load the .json using service (HttpClient) and call that from the main component (AppComponent) but still the loading is taking time and our actual component is been rendered and showing null values as .json file is loaded after the actual component is rendered

Comment: Maybe you can hide or *ngIf the form until the json loads.

Comment: every portion of the page is from .json and very dynamic for eg:drop down values, label and correspoing input type all. you want to put *ngIf for each div?

Comment: No, put the 'actual component; into an ngIf. Not every control individually. Also if you fetch more json put them into a forkJoin and wait until all information is received and only then show the component. Also you can provide more information, code etc.  A working stackblitz would be the best and maybe we can came out with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let filePath = "/assets/file.json";

this.http.get(filePath).subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Hi Adrita, we are doing the same but the issue is since it asynchronous first the component is getting and then the values are being fetched from the service.